# rollapply with embedded reference

Tags: r, zoo

My current code is this:

```
Model <- head(rollapplyr(z, width = 131, function(x)
  fitted(lm(y ~x1+ x2, data = as.data.frame(x))), by.column = FALSE)[,131],3429)
```

I would like to do this:

```
fit1 <- lm(y ~x1+ x2)
Model <- head(rollapplyr(z, width = 131, function(x) fitted(fit1),
  data = as.data.frame(x))), by.column = FALSE)[,131],3429)
```

Basically, I'm just trying to sub in `fit1` for the regression equation, but I keep getting an error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Also, please edit with the error you get.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what do you want to do , but you can factor out the formula like this:

```
form <- y ~ x1 + x2
FUN <- function(x) fitted(lm(form, data = as.data.frame(x)))
rollapplyr(z, 131, FUN, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will take a look at this and edit/improve my post accordingly...